# What is the alternate of if statement with a lot of or condtions?

Tags: vb.net

I have a panel which am using as graphics. Not what i want is that when mouse move to some points on this panel, the mouse cursor get changed. I have used the code below which is working fine, but i dont know what to do if i have 100 points or more.

```
    Dim targetpoints As New List(Of Point)
        targetpoints.Add(New Drawing.Point(50, 50))
        targetpoints.Add(New Drawing.Point(200, 50))
        targetpoints.Add(New Drawing.Point(50, 200))
        targetpoints.Add(New Drawing.Point(200, 200))

        If CheckRange(e.X, e.Y, targetpoints(0).X, targetpoints(0).Y) OrElse
            CheckRange(e.X, e.Y, targetpoints(1).X, targetpoints(1).Y) OrElse
            CheckRange(e.X, e.Y, targetpoints(2).X, targetpoints(2).Y) OrElse
                      CheckRange(e.X, e.Y, targetpoints(3).X, targetpoints(3).Y) Then
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Cross
        Else
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        End If
Private Function CheckRange(X As Integer, Y As Integer, TargetX As Integer, TargetY As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim Range As Boolean
    If Math.Abs(X - TargetX) <= (5) AndAlso Math.Abs(Y - TargetY) <= 5 Then
        Range = True
    Else
        Range = False
    End If
    Return Range
End Function
```

Comment: Note that your `CheckRange` method is overly verbose. All you need is `Return Math.Abs(X - TargetX) <= 5 AndAlso Math.Abs(Y - TargetY) <= 5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
If targetpoints.Any(Function(p) CheckRange(e.X, e.Y, p.X, p.Y)) Then
```

See the documentation for the `Any` method [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: what if we have to get that entity for which the condition satisfied?

Comment: @AnasAhmed, if you have a new question then post a new question, containing all and just the information relevant to that new question. If it's appropriate to provide a link back to this question then by all means do so.

Comment: @AnasAhmed, if you were to follow the advice of simplifying the `CheckRange` method as I suggested in my comment on the question, you could possibly do away with that method altogether, unless you wanted to call it elsewhere too. You could just change that `If` statement to `If targetpoints.Any(Function(p) Math.Abs(e.X - p.X) <= 5 AndAlso Math.Abs(e.Y - p.Y) <= 5) Then`. Otherwise, unless that method has some documentation explaining what it does, it offers no value. A simple comment on the `If` statement explaining what it does would be better.